# ActionbarSherlock and android:targetSdkVersion>13

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I am using ActionbarSherlock 4.0 - the problem is that when I set targetSdkVersion to 14 or 15 the Home button stops working - everything is fine as soon as I set it back to 13
I am testing on a tablet with 3.1 and a phone with 2.3.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what was wrong - one has to explicitly call when targetting 13+

`getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);`

Answer (score 2):

If you mean the "up" button in the ActionBar, you have to call [ActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(boolean)) when targeting API14+.

Comment: with that command I get an reaction, but I thought the meaning of that is "one level UP" - that's also the understanding I have from the appearing icon, but not what I want in my app in all cases ( solves some though ) - is there no way to get back the old behaviour?